# How do I get Castor to ignore certain XML fields?

Tags: java, xml, unmarshalling, castor

I am maintaining some complex Java code and the Castor (v1.2) unmarshaling is very slow due to quite a few "missing" Java objects.  See, the XML contains more fields than I require but Castor repeatedly tries to instantiate the Java objects, causing lots of ClassNotFound errors.

Castor Mapping File:

```
<mapping>
  <class name="com.example.imaging.product.Product">
    <map-to xml="product"/>
    <field name="productId" type="long">
      <bind-xml name="id" node="attribute"/>
    </field>
  </class>

  <class name="com.example.imaging.product.RegionConfiguration">
    <map-to xml="mediaConfiguration"/>
    <field name="name" type="string">
      <bind-xml name="name" node="attribute"/>
    </field>
    <field name="design" type="int">
      <bind-xml name="designId" node="attribute"/>
    </field>
  </class>
</mapping>
```

XML Source:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<product id="1234">
  <productImage colorId="1"/>
  <mediaConfiguration name="Front" designId="98765" />
  <color id="1" name="Red" default="true"/>
</product>
```

My problem is that the `color` field doesn't have a Java equivalent and I don't want it unmarshaled.  I tried setting `org.exolab.castor.xml.strictelements=false` in the castor.properties file but that doesn't keep it from walking the classload path and throwing ClassNotFound errors.

How can I make Castor skip over non-needed XML elements?

Comment: are you using spring to do the task ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you can't override the behavior of trying to unmarshal each element, see [the Castor reference](http://www.castor.org/reference/html/XML%20data%20binding.html#xml.mapping.overview.unmarshalling). Have you measured what the real performance impact is? It might be best just to ignore this until Castor develops better override behavior.

> If the class is not described in the mapping file, Castor will instrospect the class using the Java Reflection API to determine if there is any function of the form getXxxYyy()/setXxxYyy( x). This accessor will be associated with XML element/attribute named 'xxx-yyy'. In the future, we will provide a way to override this default behavior.

Comment: As a work around, it might be faster to create a Color class (maybe without any properties) so that it does instantiate a simple class.  Again, it probably makes sense to live with the performance penalty of the default behavior until Castor improves.